# Kubernetes Weblogic Operator installation failure

Tags: kubernetes, weblogic

I am trying to install the Kubernetes Operator on a VM host which has been initiated as the master node and has two worker nodes in two different VMs.

I had successfully installed the Operator before and it was running perfectly, before something was stuck during the upgrade of a domain and I had to clean everything up and re-install the whole Kubernetes and Kubernetes Weblogic Operator again. But at this time I have some issues that I am not able to figure out the solution as I am not an expert on this tech. (Maybe I have not deleted something that should be for the cleanup)

First, as I have cleaned up everything that I was aware of that was connected with the Kubernetes and re-installed it again following a trusted tutorial, I managed to reach the point where I had to initiate the cluster.

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

I initiated with this command and used this specific ip because I wanted to use after that the Flannel Networking using

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Flannel is deployed successfully.

After I initiated and successfully joined the other two worker nodes I got to this position:

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
master-node    Ready    control-plane   43h   v1.24.0
worker-node1   Ready    <none>          43h   v1.24.1
worker-node2   Ready    <none>          43h   v1.24.1
```

After everything is ready (or that was what I thought) I need to start installing the Kubernetes Weblogic Operator following the official documentation of Oracle. I used the Quick Start.*

[Quick Start from Oracle Documentation](https://oracle.github.io/weblogic-kubernetes-operator/quickstart/)

After pulling all images and have them in the docker in the VM, and also installing the helm Kubernetes package manager I proceed to the installation of the Operator using:

```
helm install sample-weblogic-operator kubernetes/charts/weblogic-operator \
  --namespace sample-weblogic-operator-ns \
  --set image=ghcr.io/oracle/weblogic-kubernetes-operator:3.4.0 \
  --set serviceAccount=sample-weblogic-operator-sa \
  --set "enableClusterRoleBinding=true" \
  --set "domainNamespaceSelectionStrategy=LabelSelector" \
  --set "domainNamespaceLabelSelector=weblogic-operator\=enabled" \
```

To be noted that all namespaces and services have been set up.

At this point this is where it gets messy. The operator never starts and has the following errors:

If I get the pods

```
sample-weblogic-operator-ns   weblogic-operator-85667bfb6f-fdcw6    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   406 (3m22s ago)   22h
```

And in the describe of the pod

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  20m (x1077 over 22h)    kubelet  Liveness probe failed:
  Warning  BackOff    5m12s (x4906 over 22h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  6s (x2424 over 23h)     kubelet  Readiness probe failed:
```

These are all the pods running:

[image]

Next, I tried to see the logs of the Operator and I get multiple errors which all have the same characteristic:

```
"message":"Exception thrown","exception":"\nio.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

After some digging I started to think that this was due to some networking misconfiguration and started to look into the other pods for logs and I found the following:

In coredns pod

```
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```

At this point after research I found out that this has to do something with the hosts and the IP, but it is the same point where I got lost. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, the firewall was blocking the process. I was not aware of those settings and didn't have the actual knowledge on that. Found it after a lot of searching and trying.

I have enabled the IPs of flannel and then it worked fine.